# How to send lots of emails via smtp on CodeIgniter without time out?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I'm trying to send 1000+ emails at a time via SMTP on my CodeIgniter website application, now, I loop to send it to every recipients(the same content), but PHP script timeout.

Comment: To avoid script execution time out you can set it to 0: `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: does this have to work with a ui? or can it work with in batch?

Comment: mail content,recipients and subject from a html form. I'm confused, how php back-end to execute a task over a long period of time, about 1 hour or more,and the front page after submit immediately get the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing timeout issues better to use some sort of mail queue functionality.Or add your own logic to send some certain amount of emails at a particular time using cron jobs.
Have a look on mail queue.

http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/redirected

Comment: Thanks! It likely what I want.

Answer (score 1):

at top of script add:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: Thanks! but I really want is to how to shorten the execution time of sending 1000+ emails. When I send email to all recipients at one time (not loop to send to each of them) ,it soon finished. I guess is that whether a SMTP socket connection can send multiple emails at a time.